# Entity Framework 5 Code First Migrations ready for production?

Tags: database, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I am doing some research on EF5, and came across this [question.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76082/is-entity-framework-code-first-a-bit-meaningless-useless-in-production-and-what)
The claims made in the answer make sense to me.

But now, in EF5 we have Migrations.
So lets say I've built an application with Code First, and it's now up and running for a while, and sensitive user data has been accumulated in the DB. Consider a case when the model needs some changes.

Is it completely safe to just update the POCOS and let Migrations take care of updating the DB, or are there any preparations needs to be done in order to prevent data loss ?

(Would love to here someone who had a working setup of Code First and Migrations in a live application)

Comment: if you have valuable data you would always want to backup it - not only before any upgrade to the database but probably on daily basis to not lose it in case of database failure.

Answer (score 3):

First, on production make sure that your DbMigrationsConfiguration sets `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false`. Then after you change your model, execute the command `Add-Migration`. This will generate the commands to alter your database and you can see if something is dropped before executing it. This way you have full control on what happens on your database.

Answer (score 0):

It's never completely safe to do any kind of database change, as you may have made errors in the migration code, or there might be a disk error that causes problems... lots of potential issues really, so you must make backups prior to doing a migration, or any other kind of database change.